# Regex or javascript 1 word in every X consecutive words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to come up with some regex or javascript that will as the title says get 1 random word from every X consecutive words.

for e.g I have this piece of text

"In computing, a regular expression provides a concise and flexible means to "match" (specify and recognize) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters. Common abbreviations for "regular expression" include regex and regexp."

I would like to regex 1 word every 4 words so from the first four words in the text "In computing, a regular" I would regex out 1 random word e.g computing

The need to do this for the whole text however so for example in the above there are 9 groups of 4 words. I would like to regex out one random word from each group. Hopefully I can make a quick edit in that regex so it can do the same for X word groups as well. X being any number.

I have tried all over to get something that can do this for me but I'm not getting on very well (I am new to both regex and javascript)

I think if I can use javascript to split the text into X groups of words, I can then try to get a random word from each group afterwards.

What I have so far is this:

```
var split='In computing, a regular expression provides a concise and flexible means to "match" (specify and recognize) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters. Common abbreviations for "regular expression" include regex and regexp.'.match(/[^ ]+( +[^ ]+){0,3}/g);
```

This splits the text with a comma separator into groups of 4 words (or every 3 spaces). The problem is that the separator is a comma so any comma's in the original text are also seen in the output e.g

```
In computing, a regular,expression provides a concise,and flexible means to,"match" (specify and recognize),strings of text, such,as particular characters, words,,or patterns of characters.,Common abbreviations for "regular,expression" include regex and,regexp.
```

Is there anyway to change that separator to something besides a comma? At least this way I can then try and come up with some regex that can be used on each 4 word group. I thought of maybe replacing the comma after the match but that will replace all the original commas as well of course.

I'm not sure how I will do the random word regex or javascript but having the groups sorted out I think is the first step in the right direction?

Thanks for any help or advice with this, I really appreciate it. Sorry if this is completely straightforward to some of you but I am new do this and I've tried for hours now to come up with some working solution but to no avail.

Peter

Comment: Why do you have to use regex? Regex does not have a "random" operator (that I'm aware of!) and so is unsuited to this task.

Comment: I don't have to. Javascript will do fine for all of this. I will have to look into that part after I can get the words separated in groups first. I've been playing around with so much code today trying to get something to do this but having such a weak knowledge of regex and javascript has stopped me. Usually persistent messing with code examples from all over the web gets me what I need to do but this has me stumped :)

Answer (score 1):

`.match` will return an array of matches. Then just split them by space and get a random one out of each array:

```
var text = '"In computing, a regular expression provides a concise and flexible means to "match" (specify and recognize) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters. Common abbreviations for "regular expression" include regex and regexp."';
var groups = text.match( /[^ ]+( +[^ ]+){0,3}/g );
for( var i=0 ; i<groups.length ; i++ ) {
  var words = groups[i].split( ' ' );
  console.log( words[~~(Math.random()*words.length)] );
}
```

-

`~~(Math.random()*words.length)` will give you an integer `0` to # of words (4) - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions don't support randomization, so they won't help you here.

But you can use the String.split method to transform the text into an array of individual words. Then you iterate the array in in groups of four and select a random word from each group.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
```

returns a random integer between 0 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/DqsQu/

```
var str = "In computing, a regular expression provides a concise and flexible means to \"match\" (specify and recognize) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters. Common abbreviations for \"regular expression\" include regex and regexp.";

var words = str.match(/\w+/g);
for (var i=0; i< words.length; i+=4) {    
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*4) + i;
    if (words[randNum]){
        document.write(words[randNum] + "<br>");
    }
}
​
```

Edit:

If you want to ensure that the last "group" of words always has a value, then you can do this:

```
var words = str.match(/\w+/g);
for (var i=0; i< words.length; i+=4) {
    var maxRand = Math.min(4, words.length - i);
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxRand) + i;
    document.write(words[randNum] + "<br>");
}
​
```

So, if you have the phrase "one two three four five six" the first word will be a random word from the first four words, the second group only contains the words "five" and "six" so you'll get a random word from one of those TWO words.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly but unfortunately it doesn't work inside the program I am using it in. I think the document.write is causing the problem. Is there any straight forward way without it to break up the text into groups separated by a ; for example. A regex solution will probably work well. I will then try and work with each regex match separately and get a random word from each. Thanks again

Comment: Outside the loop create a variable: var randomWords = ""; Then, 
instead of document.write do: 
`randomWords += words[randNum] " ";`

Comment: Not working I'm afraid `var str = "this is a sample text string i want to work with";

var words = str.match(/\w+/g);
var randomWords = "";
for (var i=0; i< words.length; i+=4) {    
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*4) + i;
    if (words[randNum]){
    randomWords += words[randNum] " ";
    }
}
`

Comment: Oops:  `+= words[randNum] " "` should be  `+= words[randNum] + " "`

Comment: This works perfectly now. It is giving me a random word from each group separated by a space. The only problem is that sometimes it spits out a number. I have tested it several times with different text strings and the number is the amount of spaces in the text string + 1. So if 10 spaces exist it will sometimes spit out 11?

Comment: What is causing this problem is that if the amount of spaces in the text string don't equal a multiple of 4 +1 more then it spits out a number. e.g a text string that has 17 spaces (so 4 multiple of 4, plus 1 = 17) then it works. If it doesn't add up like this it doesn't. how can this be fixed? thanks

Comment: working 100% now. you are the man aquinas! thanks a lot for helping me out!